# Pronouncing dictionaries

Tags: dictionary, phonetics

Are there any alternatives to [The CMU Pronouncing Dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict), commercial or open source?

Comment: All the online dictionaries have a pronunciation guide. Although they differ in how they represent the phonemes. Are you just looking up the odd word or do you want to gather a large collection of them for a project (i.e. text to speech)? There are also many sites with audio, would that help?

Comment: I don't know what @deadprogrammer wants this for, but I wanted a bunch of pronunciation data for a phonetics project.  For my purposes, neither an online dictionary nor audio files would have helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe the answer is definitively "no," but I do know that CMU is the most popular pronouncing dictionary in my anecdotal experience. I believe it is open source so if it's missing something, perhaps you could find a way to add it (or request it be added).

Barring that, I would check with the folks at [Language Log.](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/) They deal a lot with phonetics.

Answer (score 1):

I am searching for something similar, too. Next to it I found http://www.voxforge.org/home/downloads

Answer (score 0):

There is [CELEX 2](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/CatalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC96L14), available from the Linguistic Data Consortium, which contains phonology information and costs $300. The problem is that it's a little dated, and the English dictionary is BE, not AE.

You can use [CALLHOME](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/CatalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC97L20), too, but with $2250 it's more more expensive than CELEX.

Answer (score 0):

I found [DictionaryForMIDs](http://dictionarymid.sourceforge.net/what.html) and [desktionary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/desktionary). I haven't used either but both are open source.

Answer (score 0):

[forvo.com](http://forvo.com). Free and open.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout [Merriam-Webster](http://m-w.com) for things like this:

[stack](http://www.merriam-webster.com/cgi-bin/audio.pl?stack001.wav=stack)
[overflow](http://www.merriam-webster.com/cgi-bin/audio.pl?overfl02.wav=overflow)